# ormlite async methods throw casting exception with miniprofiler

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack, mvc-mini-profiler

When using async ormlite methods (like below), Ormlite throws the following error.
Unable to cast object of type 'StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbCommand' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand"

```
        using (IDbConnection db = await this.Conn.OpenAsync())
        {
            return await db.SelectAsync(where);
        }
```

This error only happens if we register ormlite with miniprofiler.

```
        container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(() =>
            new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(CONNECTION_STRING_GOES_HERE, DIALECT_PROVIDER_HERE)
            {
                ConnectionFilter = f => new ProfiledDbConnection((DbConnection)f, MiniProfiler.Current)
            },
            ScopedLifestyle.Scoped
        );
```

[I was informed by the Miniprofiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/issues/519) team that the issue is on OrmLite's side. Does anyone have a solution to this or a suggestion for how to proceeed?

> Indeed that would fail - it looks like they're making assumptions that
> the DbCommand is in fact a SqlDbCommand (or any other type) - that's
> simply not a safe assumption in all of ADO.NET. It's an interface that
> could be any type.
>
> I recommend filing an issue on their side as to why they're making
> this invalid assumption and what it's trying to do with that command
> (likely attempting to do something SQL Server specific).

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Daniel, did you ever hear back from the OrmLite team?

Comment: @devlord I did not. I tried to create an account on the ormlite customer support forum, but for whatever reason, my account is still not active. I reached out to them about this, so we'll see if they respond.